# CSS3 Animation Preloader - Codepen to JSFiddle not working

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to use a pre-loader that I've found over on codepen, but it seems like when I use the code off the site things don't work as expected.

I'm wondering why this may be?

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGudF

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sLmraL69/

The code :

**CSS**

```
.load {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*change these sizes to fit into your project*/
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.load hr {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    width:40%;
    height:40%;
    position:absolute;
    border-;
    animation:spin 2s ease infinite
}

.load :first-child {
    background:#35A9DA;
    animation-delay:-1.5s
}
.load :nth-child(2) {
    background:#71D0C8;
    animation-delay:-1s
}
.load :nth-child(3) {
    background:#35A9DA;
    animation-delay:-0.5s
}
.load :last-child {
    background:#35A9DA
}

@keyframes spin{
  0%,100%{ transform:translate(0) }
      25%{ transform:translate(120%) }
      50%{ transform:translate(120%, 120%) }
      75%{ transform:translate(0, 120%) }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="load">
  <hr/><hr/><hr/><hr/>
</div>
```

The element just doesn't spin and all the elements are stacked on top of each other. Not sure what I'm missing here as its not reliant on any js library.

If I add a -webkit prefix to the animation and transform properties, things act quite strangely.

Thanks!

Comment: Most probably browser prefixes. Codepen has **-prefix-free** enabled. What is the browser (and version) that you are using?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using chrome for testing. That was one of my original thoughts. I Tried adding a -webkit prefix to the animation and transform properties but things act strange. I'll look into the prefix situation.

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sLmraL69/1/) mate. It works in Chrome when the `-webkit-` is added.

Comment: Great! That seems to work for me in chrome. When I added the -webkit prefix before the boxes were just spinning in place wierdly. Maybe I missed a prefix or something. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your CodePen's CSS configured to be *prefix-free*, meaning that vendor prefixes (like `-webkit-` and `-moz-`) are automatically inserted for you where applicable.

[image: Example Configuration]

This means that when you copy over your code into JSFiddle, you no longer have this setting available to you, and the required prefixes aren't present in your code, and you'll need to add these in manually.

For the most part you can rely on [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com) for finding out whether certain CSS properties require vendor prefixes or not. For example, if we look for [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) we'll see that IE9 requires the `-ms-` prefix, old versions of Firefox require the `-moz-` prefix and older versions of Chrome and other Webkit-based browsers require the `-webkit-` prefix:

[image: Can I Use... example]

We can then add these in manually by changing:

```
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```

To:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

...and doing this for any other properties which may also require such prefixes in order for them to work.

Comment: Thank you James! This was the first time I was using code as a template that I found on Codepen and was unaware they used the prefix-free setting. I must have overlooked it, and thanks for the explination!